# I am struggling with understanding the following list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Can please someone write the following list comprehension in simple for loops and statements.

```
new_words = ' '.join([word for word in line.split() if not 
any([phrase in word for phrase in char_list])])
```

I wrote the above list comprehension in the following code but it doesn't work.

```
new_list = []
for line in in_list:
  for word in line.split():
    for phrase in char_list:  
        if not phrase in word:
          new_list.append(word)
return new_list
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `in_list`? It is not in the original comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_words = ' '.join(
    [
        word for word in line.split() 
        if not any(
            [phrase in word for phrase in char_list]
        )
    ]
)
```

is more or less equivalent to this:

```
new_list = []
for word in line.split():
    phrases_in_word = []
    for phrase in char_list:
        # (phrase in word) returns a boolean True or False
        phrases_in_word.append(phrase in word)  
     
    if not any(phrases_in_word):
        new_list.append(word)

new_words = ' '.join(new_list)
```

Comment: thanks, your code actually worked. how do I gave you points or rank you? I am new here and can't find any rank or endorse button.

Comment: @shahfaisalkhan You can hit the up or down arrow next to the answer you want to vote on. You can also select the answer that best suited your question with the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_words = ' '.join([word for word in line.split() 
                      if not any([phrase in word for phrase in char_list])])
```

is the equivalent of:

```
lst = []
for word in line.split(): 
    for phrase in char_list: 
        if phrase in word:
            break
    else:  # word not in ANY phrase
        lst.append(word)
new_words = ' '.join(lst)
```

Comment: the break statment make it break out from the loop and not do any further operation which is a problem. i need to iterate through all the words.